# Transmission-daemon inside Docker container with OpenVPN/privateinternetaccess.com port forwarding

Tags: docker, openvpn, transmission

I've been experimenting with moving my seedbox into a Docker container and I think I'm up against a chicken/egg problem:

The current seedbox setup has OpenVPN running (all internet goes through the VPN) through privateinternetaccess.com. I have a script (https://github.com/firecat53/pia_transmission_monitor) that checks with PIA for the assigned forwarded port and then updates transmission-daemon accordingly with the port and bind address.

The problem is that the assigned forwarded port is checked hourly and it can change at any time...and I need to know the port before running the Docker container so I know which ports to pass through to/from the container. I was intending to run OpenVPN inside the container as well, but without knowing in advance which port to assign to the container I'm not sure this is going to work.

A *very* hackish solution *could* be to run OpenVPN and another Docker daemon inside one container, then run the transmission container inside the OpenVPN container. This seems waay to complex though so I haven't actually tried it yet.

Am I missing something really obvious here? Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get Transmission-daemon running inside the Docker container through an OpenVPN connection to Privateinternetaccess.com.

[Here](https://github.com/firecat53/dockerfiles/tree/master/transmission) is the Dockerfile and the various configuration files and scripts needed to make this work. I'm open to any simplifications and/or alternate ways of achieving this! Some notes:

1. OpenVPN requires running the container with the --privileged flag in order to create the tun0 connection.
2. I could only make it work right by using [Pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) along with a bridge on the host to give the container it's own IP address on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to set the Docker-assigned port with `-p <publicport>:<containerport>`?

E.g., assuming that transmission listens on port 10000 inside the container, you could tell Docker "hey, expose that on port 1234, will you?" by doing `docker run -p 1234:10000 …`

Comment: That has to be done anyways...the problem is you don't know what the assigned forwarded port will be from privateinternetaccess.com until _after_ you run the port forwarding script inside the openvpn container. Therein lies the issue....

Answer (score 0):

I would look for a generic socket proxy that could copy all traffic to/from the dynamically-assigned port to one that you statically use. E.g.

```
$ docker run -p 1000 your_container /bin/bash
# PORT=$(pia_setup_script)
# proxy_command 1000 $PORT
```

Of course you can make this more elegant, but that's the general concept

Answer (score 0):

Something worth checking out along some of the same lines, though missing the vpn portion, which is nice btw. When the cycles arise I think someone will add it.

https://github.com/Ohge/Docker-TransHeadCouchRage